# Date field dont autofill value Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

My browser (chrome and firefox) [doesn`t autofill my Datefield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AXlF.png), but in safari working [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99thb.png)

I inspected my html

[HTML field have value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctIgT.png)

my **view.py**

```
    def get(self, request, slug):
       order = get_object_or_404(Order, order_number=slug)
       form = DirectorForm(instance=order)
       return render(request, 'edit_order.html', context={'form': form})
```

my **forms.py**

```
    widgets = {'order_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need datefield widget for this   you have to import datetime module in your models.py and use it to fill date or time

Comment: Thx for your answer! Maybe you could still be a little more specific.

Comment: No, my DateField working correctly, but when i edit my order, <input type="date"> doesn`t auto filling my data from my model

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific here is my github link to a simple django project i did when i first started : https://github.com/AYUSHJD098/Django-Notes
and the site is : http://www.djangonotes.tk

you just need to add " date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) " in your models.py

like this

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The value will get added automatically when you save data to your database

here is a example:

home.html

```
{% if notes %}
{% for note1 in notes %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1 class="display-4">{{note1.title}}</h1>
                <p class="lead">{{ note1.date }}</p>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <p class="lead">{{ note1.note }}</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'view_note'  pk=note1.id %}">Open</a>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea
from .models import *

class noteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = note
        fields = ('title', 'note')
        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'title'}),
            'note': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows':'16','placeholder':'note'})
        }
```

P.s sorry if i sound like a complete idoit i am very bad at explainging and i am kinda new to programming

Thanks,
ayush :)